# Oracle join two SQL select functions

Tags: oracle, function, join

I have an Oracle function that I am trying to select from which will bring back either a list of users or a list of applications they have access to depending on the parameters being passed to it.

This brings back a list of all users:

```
select * from TABLE(function_user('Users',''))
```

This brings back a list of all applications a single user has access to:

```
select * from TABLE(function_user('Apps','(Username)'))
```

Both functions return a single column called "col_val".

How can I join together both calls to bring back a list of ALL users and the list of applications that they have access to (two columns)?

I am expecting the layout to look like this:

```
Username|Application
User1|app1
User1|app2
User2|app1
...
```

Any help on this is appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: How does the function work in the first place? Isn't it reading from a `user_app` table? Why can't you read what you need directly from that table? Why are you looking to do this through the functions that use that table to begin with?

Comment: There is complicated logic in the function - unfortunately not a read from a simple set of tables which is why the function was built.

Answer (score 0):

Try a lateral inline view:

```
select x.column_value as user_name,
       y.column_value as App_name
from table( function_user('Users','')) x
cross join lateral (
   select *
   from table( function_user('Apps', '('||x.column_value||')' )) 
) y
;
```

---

Another option (simpler a bit) using `cross apply` syntax:

```
select x.column_value as user_name,
       y.column_value as App_name
from table( function_user('Users','')) x
cross apply table( function_user('Apps', '('||x.column_value||')' )) y
;
```

---

Use `outer apply` when some users has no any access rights. In this case the query is still showing the user, but `app_name` column in the resultset is null.

```
select x.column_value as user_name,
       y.column_value as App_name
from table( function_user('Users','')) x
outer apply table( function_user('Apps', '('||x.column_value||')' )) y
;
```

Comment: wouldnt the cross join just give me every combination from both data sets?

Comment: This is not ordinary cross join, but [lateral cross join](https://oracle-base.com/articles/12c/lateral-inline-views-cross-apply-and-outer-apply-joins-12cr1) (named also: lateral inline view ) --> `cross join lateral`